# How do you un-encode single and double quotes in java?

Tags: java, quotes, sanitization

I use [AntiSamy](http://code.google.com/p/owaspantisamy/) to sanitize user input and it works well. There is one problem: it encodes single and double quotes. So if I want to edit something, `my sample&apos;s` is rendered instead of `my sample's`--the single-quote becomes encoded.

To **clarify**: The broswer renders the quotes correctly, but they get saved in my db as HTML entities. So when a user loads a post for editing, the HTML entities are displayed in the text field.

1. Is there a way to get around this limitation?
2. Should I use/are there any different tool?

My users can post code and a variety of other stuff. So AntiSamy does a great job there. But I don't want to convert single and double quotes in normal text.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String s = "string unencode &apos; &quot;NOW&quot;";
String unencoded = s.replaceAll("&apos;", "'").replaceAll("&quot;","\"");
myTextField.setText(unencoded);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the AntiSamy does not have a reversing method, this thing in particular can be handled by `StringEscapeUtils.unesacpeHtml(..)` from commons-lang.

Browsers know how to show `&apos;`, so there should not be a problem. Use the above only if you are going to display the text in an textarea or other input-control, or outside of a browser.

Comment: sorry, I did not explain myself well. I'm talking about when a user loads a post for editing, the text field displays the raw text, which contains HTML entities. So AntiSamy is encoding my stuff before it gets to the DB. This is fine. I just don't want it to encode single and double quotes in normal text--like StackOverFlow, for example. They encode everything, but they quotes in leave normal text alone. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: In addition, StringUnescapeUtils can not be used as it might encode dangerous input. I guess I just want to be selective about what I encode and do not encode.

Comment: then my first paragraph should suit you

Comment: @dee - use it only to unescape the input, for the sake of displaying. You will pass the edited input through AntiSamy again after that

Comment: StringEscapeUtils will not work. It will encode potentially dangerous input. As it encodes single quotes, it will also encode HTML brackets and script samples, no?

Comment: sorry, just to clarify: You mean I should use it when loading the text from the database to output in the form fields?

Comment: @dee yes. But note one thing - you need that only in a textarea. Text inputs handle it properly. And in the textarea you just have to verify whether there isn't a closing `</textarea>` tag in the input - it will screw the page

Comment: If it is only about the quotes, you can as well go for Leo's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If all what you need is to escape potentially dangerous characters in the input, you can store that input in the database in its raw form and encode it on output.

If encoding process is more complex (i.e. some tag whitelists or formatting rules are applied), you can store two versions of the input - an encoded HTML version for display and a raw version for editing, and update the HTML version when the raw version is modified.

Comment: thank you. It's a little bit tricky because some users can edit other people's posts. This means the raw text must be sanitized to. But it must be sanitized for hamrful content, yet keeping complex formatting rules and sample code... it should just not encode quotes in normal text.

Comment: a great example is how StackOverFlow does it. They sanitize everything. But when you go to edit your post, everything is fine. The single and double quotes are not encoded.

Comment: @dee: I believe StackOverflow uses the second approach described above.